# How can I echo a string with hard line wrap?

Tags: bash

I am writing a very simple bash script that asks questions that include text from previous answers. For example:

```
questionText="Hi $userName, I'm going to ask you some questions. At the end of the process, I'll output a file that might be helpful to you."
echo "$questionText"
```

Some of these questions are quite long. The output from `echo` soft-wraps in my macOS Terminal window, but by character rather than by word. How do I hard-wrap the output to a specific width in characters, by word?

I can't manually add the breaks to `$questionText` because the included variables could be any length.

My searches all lead me to `fmt` and `fold`, but those want text files as input, not variables.

What I'm looking for is something like `echo`, but with an option to word wrap the output to a specified width.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My searches all lead me to `fmt` and `fold`, but those want text files as input, not variables.

Just use a pipe:

```
printf '%s\n' "$questionText" | fold
```

Using the `-s` option will make `fold` only wrap on white space characters, and not in the middle of a word:

```
printf '%s\n' "$questionText" | fold -s
```

Comment: Thanks! So much better than my workaround of using a `tmp.txt` file.

Comment: Furthermore note that you can use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings): `fold <<< "${questionText}"`